# User experience when multisession detected?

Tags: security, session, user-experience

I am not sure what the best experience should be in this usecase:
User X is logged in to his account from device A.
User Y (or user X) logs in to X's account from device B.
System detects a login from a different device for an already logged in account.

Now what will the system do?
- Kick the first guy out without letting device B user know?
- Display a warning on both devices?
- Ask both device users a secret Q to know who is right and allow that guy in?
- Something else?

Eventually, only 1 device can be logged in to the account. although i am not sure how to handle this: If user logs in to account from Firefox then opens Internet explorer and logs in, the IP / device is same, so how to catch that?

Answer (score 0):

To your last question, if whatever framework you're using supports both a session-level storage and an application-level storage, when a user logs in, you can stored their "logged-in-ness" as a boolean in the session and hold a list of usernames in the application storage. If a user tries to log in, and is present in the application storage but not the session storage, it's a duplicate login from a different browser. Handling the end of a session when the user doesn't explicitly log out is a challenge though.

As far as the user experience, it really depends on your purpose. In most cases, I would expect to be able to run concurrent sessions without a problem, so I might get upset if I couldn't. Another option would be to inform device B that the user already has a session running, and he must close session on device A before continuing. That way if the same user is on both, he has maximum control. If they are different users, and device A has the valid account, he continues working without interruption. If device B has the valid user, he knows that his account has been compromised. It's probably his fault for being sloppy with a password and he needs to get further help.